# Can we move all the catch from a chain of try-catch-catch...so on to a different function for prevent code repetition?

Tags: java, exception

I have this code with a try-catch chain which is repeated in multiple places.

```
void fun1(){
    try{
        task1();
    }
    catch(Exception1 ex){
        handleEx1();
    }
    catch(Exception2 ex){
        handleEx2();
    }
    catch(Exception3 ex){
        handleEx3();
    }
    catch(Exception4 ex){
        handleEx4();
    }
}
```

```
void fun2(){
    try{
        task2();
    }
    catch(Exception1 ex){
        handleEx1();
    }
    catch(Exception2 ex){
        handleEx2();
    }
    catch(Exception3 ex){
        handleEx3();
    }
    catch(Exception4 ex){
        handleEx4();
    }
}
```

The catch chain is being used in multiple places and thus is being repeated as it is.
Now, is this recommended or even possible to only move the catch part to a different function.

What else can be done to prevent this code repetition?

Comment: Have you `fun`s throw the exceptions that they don't want to handle

Comment: @MadProgrammer then the funs would throw like a lot of exception, around 7. It would look like void `fun throws Exception1, Exception2, Exception3, ...Exception7 ()`. Which doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: one possible solution in mind is write a function that will handle exception `void handleException(CustomException e) { if(e instanceof Exception1) { handleEx1(); } else {...}...; else throw e; } `.  `Exception1` have to be an implementation of `CustomException`

Comment: @corvo So, you have a catch 22.  Either you need to re-throw the exceptions you don't want to handle, or you handle them all each time.  You could, as has been suggested have a method which would otherwise "consumes" them (and throws what ever is not handled), but this seems a bit like an anti-pattern to me (IMHO)

Comment: @MadProgrammer if I shouldn't consume them in a single method then there must another way to reduce this code duplication right?

Comment: @corvo Sure, throw them and let the caller deal with them.  If the process of handling the exception is the same, you could have support methods which handle each case individually.  The problem with "god" methods is they are hard to maintain don't always deal with edge cases and become a "convenient" dumping ground for work, which really should be handled by the developer.  IMHO